# "Failed - Network Error" is appeared when we download the file using testcafe

Tags: testing, download, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60KCh.png)verified the accessibility of Testcafe in mac settings

Please find the attached image for the reference

Answer (score 1):

The information you provided is insufficient.  I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add required information and sample code to reproduce the issue. If you can't share the info publicly, please send it to support@devexpress.com